# Windows Machine Learning (winML) on ARM

Tags: c++, arm

I am trying to get a [winML](https://github.com/microsoft/Windows-Machine-Learning) compiled on `ARM64`, but I received the following error:

> Error LNK2001 unresolved external symbol "void __cdecl
>   ConcurrentLoadModel(class std::vector,class
>   std::allocator >,class std::allocator,class
>   std::allocator > > > const &,unsigned int,unsigned int,bool)"
>   (?ConcurrentLoadModel@@YAXAEBV?$vector@V?$basic_string@_WU?$char_traits@_W@std@@V?$allocator@_W@2@@std@@V?$allocator@V?$basic_string@_WU?$char_traits@_W@std@@V?$allocator@_W@2@@std@@@2@@std@@II_N@Z) WinMLRunner C:\Users\t\Downloads\Windows-Machine-Learning-master\Windows-Machine-Learning-master\Tools\WinMLRunner\WinMLRunnerStaticLib.lib(Run.obj) 1

I am using `VS 2019`. Any suggestions on how to resolve the error?

Answer (score 0):

It looks like the implementation of `ConcurrentLoadModel` in WinMLRunnerScenarios library doesn't build for ARM64 yet. In the meantime, if you aren't using the ConcurrentLoad scenario, you can just comment out the [following lines](https://github.com/microsoft/Windows-Machine-Learning/blob/master/Tools/WinMLRunner/src/Run.cpp#L559) and it will build just fine:

```
        if (args.IsConcurrentLoad())
        {
            ConcurrentLoadModel(modelPaths, args.NumThreads(), args.ThreadInterval(), true);
            return 0;
        }
```